# Magento2 set custom options after media or before tabs

Tags: magento2, custom-options, tabs

Magento2 set custom options on product details page

1. after - product.info.media
2. before - tabs

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you share screenshot for more details

Comment: Did you mean to put custom block after product.info.media?

Comment: If yes, you can try something like this: ```<referenceContainer name="product.info.media">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Script" name="script_test" cacheable="false" template="Vendor_Module::script.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>```

Comment: Yes I want to move customizable options set from admin after product.info.medis

Comment: Ok, i've added one option, and i see thad customizable options are shown in product_addtocart_form , so you have to move whole add to cart form.

Comment: to move whole form try ```<move element = "product.info" destination = "product.info.media" after="-" />``` in your ```catalog_product_view.xml```